# How to upgrade to php 7.2 version in xampp

Tags: xampp, php7

My current php version from xampp (lampp) is 7.0.9 . I would like to upgrade it to 7.2.

I saw this post: https://askubuntu.com/a/856794/793678 , but is not about xampp. Or this one : [How to upgrade the php version in Lampp in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997317/how-to-upgrade-the-php-version-in-lampp-in-ubuntu) . That guy needs to upgrade it from 5 to 7. I want from 7.0.9 - 7.2

Or is there a way/trick to have multiple versions of php installed on XAMPP ?

Thank you

Comment: http://us3.php.net/git.php

Comment: @ElderGeek is that will update my php version from phpinfo() from lampp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I found no solutions , I had to reinstall xampp with the latest version. I did it like this :

`sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall` will keep the `htdocs`(your project), `temp`(I have no clue) and `var`(databases) folder intact then download the latest version from [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

```
sudo chmod 777 your downloaded file
sudo ./your donwloaded file
```

Be aware that all of your virtual host settings etc will be lost, so It would be wise to have a back up of all of the settings and configurations.

Comment: The better solution is to stick with the versions provided in the repositories. [The Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html) may be helpful.